# Excel crashes trying to run similar VBA macros consecutively

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am relatively new to VBA however I have been able to find code and solutions to fit most of my requirements for a project I am working on. I have been unable however to find a solution to the following problem.

I have 4 DBF files in the same directory that are linked to a program\application that imports the data from them into the program. I am trying to export data to these DBF files from an Excel workbook.

I found the below code which I have adapted to fit my situation. To get it to work, I found that I first needed to create an .accdb file for each of these DBF files by opening and closing them with Access. I then created 4 macros with 4 sets of similar code to export data into the 4 DBF (.accdb) files. I also updated Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 in the code and enabled the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToDBF()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.dbf;"    
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "TableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable  
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The problem I have encountered is that whilst the macros all work individually, Excel crashes if I try to run each macro one after the other. One macro (it doesn't matter which one) will always work before Excel crashes when trying to run a second macro (there is no error message - Excel closes and when I reopen it it says it has recovered the workbook).

The only way I have found they will all work without crashing is by closing and reopening Excel after running each macro.

I am wondering if someone has any idea why this would be happening and if there is a solution ?

Comment: Is this your actual modified code? When you say "DBF" files do you mean dBaseIV? If the goal is to get data into .dbf files, why do you need 4 Access files? Why not just 1 Access file and 4 tables? Why is data in Excel to begin with? Edit question to provide sample data.

Comment: I see now it is not your actual code. And providing data would be nice but probably not critical.

Comment: I adapted code to connect with Access 2010 file. Run 4 procedures and cannot replicate issue.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question and I appreciate you continuing to pursue this before I was able to get back to you. Yes, the DBF files are old dBase IV files. 

The data is in Excel to begin with as the Excel file is my primary file which I will be doing work and calculations in.
The number of fields I am updating with each macro are 5, 15, 53 and 22 respectively.

Comment: Any suggestions for me to try at my end ?

Comment: Not really. I would probably eliminate Excel. Or have Access set links to Excel worksheet and manage the import/export from Access.

Comment: I can't eliminate Excel unfortunately. What I am doing won't work without it. I will have a look at your other suggestion and may also try linking the DBF files to the 1 Access file. I don't have much experience at using Access. I created 4 Access files because that was how it worked out when I was setting it up and I also had some concerns that the program\application that imports the data from these DBF files would not import properly if they were all linked to one Access file. I will give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Linking the 4 DBF files to 1 Access file has the same outcome for me. I think your procedure worked because you imported\created the tables in Access. I have done the "link to Data Source" option in Access. I need to do this so the DBF files themselves have their data altered. A program\application then accesses the updated data. I need to be able to get the export to the DBF files working from the Excel file, if at all possible.

Comment: So your code is trying to connect to dbf files with Microsoft Ace connection string? You should show your actual code. Unfortunately, I don't have dBase app and attempt to set a link to dbf file in Access fails as does connection string in Excel VBA. It's been quite a while since I had to work with dbf data.

Comment: Your request to show the actual code prompted me to check it again. I then realised that I hadn't disclosed that I added a line of code to delete the old data in the DBF files before adding the new data. Removing this code from all 4 macros solved my problem. I was able to successfully add the code back on a different line. The line I previously had it on was taken from an answer on this site. Thanks for your help and persistence. I should have put that code in my original post.